# Scala Regex Capturing on Positive Lookaheads

Tags: regex, scala

I am attempting to use positive look-aheads to match on an arbitrary number of strings such that one can achieve the logic of 'foo' AND 'bar AND ... etc where the regex would match and on content that contained 'foo' and 'bar' and capture those occurrences in a given text blob.

I am using positive look-aheads to allow for any ordering. And we do not care about the cases so I've made the matching case insensitive.

An example regex is as follows:

```
(?i)(?=.*\b(foo)\b)(?=.*\b(bar)\b)
```

Now, while this appears to work in various testers (http://regex101.com) it seems to fail in the following Scala code:

```
val regex = """(?i)(?=.*\b(foo)\b)(?=.*\b(bar)\b)""".r
val results = regex.findAllIn("foo zinc bar")
val resultsList = result.toList

results ~ non-empty iterator
resultsList ~ List()
```

So as it stands I've confirmed that the regex seems to be formed properly and captures on various testing apps and that Scala does indicate there was some sort of match, but generates no resulting captures.

Any explanation as to why Scala seems to behave differently or any fixes would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need to do this with regex?

Comment: Normally no, but the circumstances demand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookarounds and Anchors (look-ahead, look-behind) are not directly part of the match, meaning the elements there will not be captured.

```
scala> "a(?=b)".r findFirstIn "babb"
res8: Option[String] = Some(a)
```

As you can see only "a" is part of the match, not the following "b".

Your regex matches only a position and no character is captured.

```
" foo zinc bar"
 ^
```

You could say the match occurs at position "0" an captures no result. 
But the match is valid as the lookahead has been checked and passed.

**Capturing parentheses** only work within the matched characters not within lookarounds.

For the problem you described you can go with

```
val regex = """(?i).*?\b(foo)\b.*?\b(bar)\b""".r

scala> for (regex(a,b) <- regex findFirstIn "foo zinc bar") yield (a,b)
res18: Option[(String, String)] = Some((foo,bar))
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! My only problem with your solution is the rigid ordering (That was what was so great about the look aheads). If you have any thoughts on how to do that without combinatorially generating several regexs I would appreciate it.

Comment: Could you give some more explanation of what you trying to achieve. maybe some more examples. Then I could look into it.